# Reduce Window title bar in Budgie

Tags: budgie

I have recently installed budgie on a Linux Mint machine.

It's a beautiful thing however the windows title bar are huge.

Is there any way to reduce its size?

Comment: I may be able to help, but have no idea what budgie is. Please edit question.